# RSA with $\lambda(n)$ or $\varphi(n)$

Tags: rsa

The [PKCS #1 v2.0](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt) specifications suggest using $\lambda(n) = \mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$. What is the benefit of choosing $\lambda(n)$ over $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ in RSA key generation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choosing $\lambda(n)$ rather than $\varphi(n)$ may result in a smaller private exponent.

Comment: ... and as there are attacks against RSA with (too) small exponent, one couldn't detect that the exponent is too small if one just looks at the exponent one gets using $\varphi$ instead of $\lambda$.

Comment: @fgrieu You're wrong about the "always": The calculation of the modular inverse is done with a smaller exponent by a factor of at least 2. But that does not necessarily imply, that the product $ed$ is smaller (it usually is). Small number example: $n=7\cdot 11 \Rightarrow \varphi=60; \lambda=30$. For $e=11$, we get that $d=11$ in both cases ($11 \cdot 11 = 1$ for both moduli).

Comment: @tylo: very right. My mistake. I wish I could edit (rather than delete) wrong comments.

Comment: @j.p., why one cannot detect the exponent is small if one just looks at the exponent one gets using phi instead of lambda?

Comment: @dannycrane The attacks work if the exponent you get with $\lambda$ is too small. If you calculate $d$ using $\varphi$, you generally get a bigger value. (In practice it's unlikely to be a problem, but for evaluations you might have to use $\lambda$.)

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with the small exponent attack, since the public key here is chosen in the same way whether you use $\phi(n)$ or $\lambda(n)$. So, this is like a "shortcut" in the decryption that does not weaken RSA at all.

Comment: @YehudaLindell : $\;\;\;$ (I don't know anything about that attack, but) I got the impression from j.p.'s comment that the attack works whenever the _smallest_ $d$ is (too) small. $\:$ Using $\phi(n)$ instead of $\lambda(n)$ wouldn't let the key generation algorithm detect that. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the key generation algorithm detecting. The attack indeed works when the smallest $d$ is small. However, since $e$ is chosen in the same way whether using $\lambda$ or $\phi$, this means that the $d$ obtained via $\lambda$ is an equivalent decryption exponent. Thus any attack is an attack on the ORIGINAL scheme. I'm not sure if this answers your question...

Comment: @YehudaLindell : $\:$ I mean "the key generation algorithm detecting" that the smallest $d$ is (too) small and thus not outputting that key-pair. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @YehudaLindell, I agree that detecting small exponent has nothing to do with the key generation algorithm. But I guess Ricky's point is that since lambda is smaller or equal to phi, when we select $e$, it is more probable that $d$ ends up with a small value, i.e., the order of the group defined by $lambda$ is smaller than the order of the group defined by $phi$.

Comment: @dannycrane I'm sorry but I just don't follow this. The ring is exactly the same using lambda and phi.  This is due to the fact that e remains the same in both cases.

Comment: @RickyDemer Are you referring to a step in the key generation algorithm where the length of d is checked? I didn't know that this is done. If so, this certainly won't be small enough to be detected. But what I'm trying to say is that it makes no difference since this doesn't change the RSA function in any way.

Comment: @YehudaLindell : $\;\;\;$ I'm referring to a hypothetical step in which the key generation algorithm would check the length of d. $\:$ What is "this"? $\:$ If key generators had such a step, then it would certainly change the distribution of public keys. $\:$ Whether that change makes a difference would depend on the rejection criteria for d. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I see. Well EVERY e has a d based on phi and a d based on lambda, and so if you wanted to reject based on lambda, you would have to reject everything. :-)

Comment: @YehudaLindell, I was confused in the previous one and now it is cleared. New questions: which step in the RSA algorithm do we reject small e? That is not part of the RSA algorithm, isn't it?

Comment: Any value of e that is relatively prime to phi is fine. So e=3 is usually fine.

Comment: @YehudaLindell : $\;\;\;$ "is usually fine" in the sense of "won't be a problem as long as its relatively prime to phi". $\:$ However, if the primes are chosen randomly (rather than specifically to let e=3 work), then 3 would be relatively prime to phi only about 1/4 of the time. $\:$ (So, in that sense, it's not usually fine.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @dannycrane : $\:$ See my previous comment. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @all: I have the feeling the long discussion here was triggered by my comment not being precise enough. Sorry for the confusion. The attacks I was referring to were against a too short *private* exponent $d$ (Wiener and later). The check of the length of $d$ (derived using $\lambda$) is required at the end (2nd last sentence) of Appendix B.3.1 of [NIST FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf).

Comment: @RickyDremer I wasn't being precise. I wanted to focus on the fact that e=3 is fine security wise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25651/discussion-on-answer-by-ricky-demer-rsa-with-lambdan-or-varphin).

Comment: @YehudaLindell If you still have open questions, either [try to solve them in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25651/discussion-on-answer-by-ricky-demer-rsa-with-lambdan-or-varphin) or simply post a new question… thanks.